# Perl IPC::Run, kill process upon death of parent

Tags: perl, signals

Is there an option one can give to [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm) which kills the process upon the parent dying? Or alternatively a simple way to kill child processes when the parent dies? I know I can do this by catching signals in the parent, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if a simple way to do this already exists. I understand that this may not catch `SIGKILL`, but that's okay, I plan to kill the parent in a more reasonable manner.

Comment: You can use `kill('HUP', -$$);` in END block. This will kill parent and it's childs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an END block to clean up.

```
my @ipc_run_harnesses;
END { $_->kill_kill for @ipc_run_harnesses }

...
for my $start ( 1..2 ) {
    push @ipc_run_harnesses, IPC::Run::start( "while true; do sleep 1; echo running $start; done" );
}
sleep 10;
exit;
```

Comment: The OP will probably want `use sigtrap qw(die normal-signals);` to help ensure the `END` block is executed, especially if he is killing the parent. +1